# Are these correct/meaningful sentences?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, sentence

1. I got baffled by his reaction.
2. Being expelled from school literally baffled me.
3. I don't know what baffled me more: if his words or his body language.

Comment: Only the second one flows well. The other two are ungrammatical. "I *was* baffled by his reaction" and remove *if* from the last one.

Comment: They're "correct" and "meaningful", though not quite idiomatic.  I'd use "I *was* baffled by his reaction" and "I don't know *which* baffled me more".  (And as Mr Vane suggests, remove the "if".)

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sentence 1

**Is it correct?**

Syntactically and grammatically, it is correct. Though, I should mention that it is not *formally* written since you made use of the word "got" (pejorative in this case) instead of a more formal word such as "became" or "was".


**Is it meaningful?**

Yes, provided that context is given.

## Sentence 2

**Is it correct?**

Yes. Although, there is absolutely no reason to employ the word "literally" here. You cannot figuratively be baffled; there's not a metaphorical or non-literal use of the word baffled – at least to my knowledge.

**Is it meaningful?**
Yes, provided that context is given.

## Sentence 3

**Is it correct?**
No. Remove the word "if" and then it'll be grammatically and syntactically correct.

**Is it meaningful?**
Yes, provided that context is given.